# Determining when nested firebase database ref.on calls have finished

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have database designed (roughly) as follows:

```
"users": {
  "userId1": {
    "challenges" {
     "challengeId1"=true,
     "challengeId2"=true
    }
  }, 
  "userId2": {
    "challenges" {
     "challengeId1"=true,
     "challengeId3"=true
    }
  }
  ...
  "userIdN": {...}
}          
"challenges": {
  "challengeId1": {
     "title"="Title 1
    }
  },
  "challengeId2": {
     "title"="Title 2
    }
  },
  "challengeId3": {
     "title"="Title 3
    }
  }
}
```

In my client I make the following nested calls:

```
const fetchChallengeList = (currUser) => {
  firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currUser.uid}/challenges`).on('child_added', snapshot => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/challenges/${snapshot.key}`).on('value', snapshotChall => {
      // Dispatch some stuff to UI
    });
  });
};
```

This generally works great and keeps everything in sync. Using .on ensures that every time a new challenge is added (to user:challenges) or an existing challenge is modified, then firebase updates the UI.

The problem is on initial load. Ideally, I'd like to wait to update the UI (e.g., show a loading icon) until the EXISTING challenges for a user initially are finished loading. Otherwise, the UI tends to feel jolting and expand over the course of 5-10 seconds. Because the calls are all asynchronous and remain open, I have no idea when the initial set has finished loading. Is there any way to keep track of this?

Comment: look at JavaScript `Promise` and `.then`

Comment: I'm familiar with Promise and .then, as well as Promise.all. But I'm not sure where that gets me here. .on('child_added') stays open and returns a value for each (child) challenge. You don't know a-priori how many its going to return. And even if you did, the nested firebase callback occurs asynchronously and within different scopes. The nested callbacks don't know about one another. So there's no way that I can see to use a Promise and .then.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a method to show/hide the loader something like

```
toggleLoader(display) => {
  // dont know the framework you are using 
  if (display) {
     $('.loader').show();
  } else {       
     $('.loader').hide();
  } 
}
```

You could then call this method after the challenges have been loaded

```
const fetchChallengeList = (currUser) => {
  firebase.database().ref(`/users/${currUser.uid}/challenges`).on('child_added', snapshot => {
    firebase.database().ref(`/challenges/${snapshot.key}`).on('value', snapshotChall => {
      // Dispatch some stuff to UI
      toggleLoader(false);
    });
  });
};
```

I would also put some error handling in to switch the loader off incase of an error.

Comment: The firebase calls are asynchronous. If there is more than one challenge, your answer would stop the loader after the first challenge was retrieved.

Comment: I get that its asynchronous, hence the reason the code sits in the callback? https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/keeping-our-promises-and-callbacks_76.html

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something. But let's assume I have 3 challenges. That means the nested ref.on will be called 3 separate times and then the callback containing the toggleLoader will be called 3 separate times. That means the first time it's called, the UI will display and the 2nd and 3rd callbacks will show precisely what I'm trying to avoid. (I've run the code with a console log to confirm). But again, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're suggesting.

Comment: Also, I can't use .then, as the article you sent suggests, because I'm calling .on, which unlike .once does not return a Promise. I need to use .on to ensure changes to challenges are automatically synced.

Comment: @Paul I see what you are saying. It is tricky I think to then get your required result. What you could maybe do is get a total of the `child_added` from the first call back with `getChildrenCount()` and increment a counter on the second. Once they equal the same toggle the loader off. Otherwise I would suggest using fadeIns on your UI to not make the transition so jumpy.